# Search and select multiple rows with different values then store into array?

Tags: php, mysqli

Apologies if this has been asked before.

So here is my table:

```
|---ID---|---Colour--|
|---01---|----RED----|
|---02---|----BLUE---|
|---03---|----RED----|
```

I want to get ID 01 and 03 and store them into an array in one query:

```
SELECT ID FROM `users` WHERE `ID` IN ( 01, 03 )
```

and put it into an array that looks something like this:

```
$ID[0] = "01";
$ID[1] = "03";
```

Here is my PHP code for the query:

```
$test = "01";
$test2 = "03";

$checkID = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE ID IN = ('" . $test . "', '" . $test2 . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$checkID);
```

How would I go about inserting the results into an array? Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do a loop using [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $ID[] = $row['ID'];
}
```

note:
(1) syntax is `WHERE ID IN ()` without the `=`
(2) your query is `$checkID` so you need `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$checkID);` not `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$checkUser);`

also, not sure why are you selecting the `ID` using the `ID`.

Comment: Great worked a treat thanks, (just so you know you missed a close bracket after $result)

Comment: glad to help. I have added the missing bracket.